# Deploying rails app to heroku, sendgrid email links not viable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, sendgrid

I am working my way through the Michael Hartl rails tutorial, and am currently in the process of pushing the web app to Heroku. (app functions correctly in local server)

I am using sendgrid to facilitate sending email to users to activate accounts. When a user creates an account the email sends correctly and is received by the user. The reset link however does not function.

On the local server the email produces a link with url localhost:3000/ etc....
which works fine.

However on the heroku deployment, the link within the email produces HTML codes for the symbols "<" and ">". Enclosing the url within them like so....

```
http://<app-1234>.heroku-app.com/ etc...
```

which does not function as a valid link. Removing the "<>" tags manually causes the activation link to function.

I assume there is some setting within sendgrid I can alter to prevent the "<>" tags being added to the url but I am having no luck finding an answer. I hope my question is clear? Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it says to enter

```
    host = <your heroku app>.herokuapp.com
```

in the config/environments/production.rb file, don't actually put the < and > symbols.  Just put the name of your app.

You would put:

```
    host = 'app-1234.herokuapp.com'
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed this... well! Many thanks for your reply, easily solved.

Comment: No problems :-)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the link `@url = "http://<app-1234>.heroku-app.com/users/sign_in"`. In the next line edit this @url with using gsub method which is used to modify and replace characters of string. Do `@url.gsub!("<app-1234>", "app-1234")` and then send that new @url object to user.

Comment: I was about to do something very similar. But luckily the problem was me being an idiot.